# how to change row to column in flutter by animation

Tags: flutter, animation, row

How can i achieve this animation in flutter

want to arrange row widget to column widget when the page is expanded shows in gif

[image]

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/68906602/15215450

Comment: Have you looked into hero widgets? https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/hero-animations